# Serving images with PHP very slow

Tags: php, performance, image, .htaccess, alias

I allow my website users to upload images and then I then serve up the images using a PHP script. However, this is noticeably slower than a static link.

The reason I use PHP to serve the images is because I am trying to prevent people from being able to access the folder which stores the images.

Should I make use of an .htaccess file? I'm also thinking about an ALIAS in the httpd but not sure how to make use of this or whether it's suitable at all - could i reference a folder outside the root using this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

`header("Content-type: " . filetype($file) . "\n");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"{$image}\"\n");
header("Content-Length: ".(string)(filesize($file)));
@readfile($file);`

Comment: How much slower? It shouldn't be TOO slow. One little tip is to start opening the file right at the beginning, giving the HDD a small amount of time to move some of it into the cache while PHP is being executed, resulting in more of the file being in the cache, and a faster read. :)

Comment: Post your code. "It's slow" is not good enough to help us troubleshoot

Comment: Definitely use `readfile()` to read the file, that helps a lot. But yeah, htaccess helps a lot. Don't ever use `file_get_contents` if all you're doing is passing it directly to the browser.

Comment: If all you want is to avoid peopele from viewing the folder a .htaccess sounds more reasonable. You can get creative with modrewrite too

Comment: whoops my edit hasn't formatted properly but gives an idea of how I output the image. Sorry about being vague but slow means 1-2 secs which obviously isn't suitable - it doesn't seem to cache either as a refresh is the same load time.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Options -Indexes` inside a `Directory` tag to disable indexes. However, you should go a step farther than this.

For security and general filesystem hygiene, you should keep your assets (images, etc) in directories separate from your code.

Then you can add this to your apache config:

```
<Directory /directory/where/assets/are>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RemoveHandler .php
        RemoveType .php
        php_flag engine off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

This will disable any execution of files as scripts in your asset directory as well as disable file listing, but allow anyone to download these files. It is important to secure directories with user-uploaded files in this way because they may upload malicious php scripts which you can then host.

Comment: Cheers for that - I'm thinking I should now serve static images  after reading around and because php is too slow. I will randomly generate their filenames and store in this directory you mention above. Do you think that will work?

Answer (score 3):

Use a .htaccess file with the single line:

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Then, the user can access the folder but can't see anything in it.

Alternatively, add a file called `index.html` but leave it blank (or include a "You may not view this page" message)